# UISearchBar minimal style with scope buttons bug?

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar

Something wrong happen when i set minimal style to search bar. My code here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    sc = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    sc.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    sc.delegate = self;
    sc.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    sc.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    [sc.searchBar setPlaceholder:@"Search"];
    [sc.searchBar setSearchBarStyle:UISearchBarStyleMinimal];
    [sc.searchBar sizeToFit];
    [sc.searchBar setScopeButtonTitles:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"item1",@"item2",@"item3", nil]];
    sc.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = sc.searchBar;
}
```

result (before touch inside): [image]

When i touch search bar its starting looks normal. Other search bar styles works right.

**edit**

Tried this way; scope buttons appear for the second like at the picture and then gone.

```
-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [sc.searchBar setScopeButtonTitles:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"item1",@"item2",@"item3", nil]];
}
```

**edit2**

When i put `[sc.searchBar setShowsScopeBar:YES]` in `viewDidLoad` method i get third version (items under search bar before touch):

[image]

and after touch interface looks normal again:

[image]

Comment: Let's start with: Why are you setting it to `UISearchBarStyleMinimal`?

Comment: Then, why the `[sc.searchBar sizeToFit];` ? It's my first time seeing this. Is there something wrong with the constraints you're using?

Comment: Because i can, i guess. @ArminM Actually application look much better with minimal style.

Comment: You're setting the `sc.searchBar.delegate = self;` twice as well... Maybe you should clean up your code and comment out unnecessary lines first and see what happens?

Comment: But... It doesn't look much better from what you're showing me in your question! According to Apple's documentation: "The style UISearchBarStyleMinimal provides no default background color or image but will display one if customized as such." That's the only difference.

Comment: Seen that in tutorial. Removing sizeToFit: did nothing change. @ArminM

Comment: After one touch inside search bar it begins to look right. So i guess there is a way for fix it. @ArminM

Comment: Oh I see what's the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Apple's Documentation on [`UISearchBarStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchBar/searchBarStyle):

> This property can be used together with `barStyle`. The style
>   `UISearchBarStyleMinimal` provides no default background color or image
>   but will display one if customized as such.

So when you set the `searchBarStyle` to `UISearchBarStyleMinimal` it removes the background image and color, so it's essentially transparent. Now to show Scope Bar buttons, you have to set the `showsScopeBar` property to `YES` before setting the titles. So:

```
[sc.searchBar setShowsScopeBar:YES];
[sc.searchBar setScopeButtonTitles:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"item1",@"item2",@"item3", nil]];
```

Comment: @OlegSobolev I tried it myself, and what fixes it was setting the `showsScopeBar` property to `YES` before setting the scope bar buttons' titles. Check the new answer.

Comment: Did you get the same result as I did? @Armin

Comment: Yes. Without the `[sc.searchBar setShowsScopeBar:YES];` it looked exactly like your result.